# i have tried downloading an image using google appscript but the response.getAs() or any other functions always returns 4 bytes as Blob. why?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

i have tried downloading an image using google appscript but the response.getAs() or any other functions always returns 4 bytes as Blob.

In google form i am trying to add an imageitem using appscript from internet and download it to avoid further URLFetch calls.

While showing from the disk (for offline file loaded from Google Drive) it works absolutely fine. However when loading from the internet for the first time it is failing.

Exception: Could not add image, please wait a minute and try again.

File blob is just 4 bytes all the time

Can someone pitch in to help.

folder - destination folder in google drive to save file
fileName - fileName of the downloaded image
fileURL - public url of the image

```
function downloadImage(folder, fileName, fileURL) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fileURL);
  if(response.getResponseCode() == 200){
    var fileBlob = response.getAs("image/jpeg");
    var file = folder.createFile(fileName+".jpeg",fileBlob,MimeType.JPEG);
    return file;
    debugger;  // Stop to observe if in debugger
  }else{
    Logger.log("Whats this now???");
  }
}
```

Size of the file is 400 KB, but it is not working for any image i have tried downloading.

Comment: The below code always returns 4 bytes. var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fileURL);
  if(response.getResponseCode() == 200){
    var fileBlob = response.getAs("image/jpeg");
      Logger.log("fileBlob="+fileBlob.getDataAsString());

Comment: Please add the relevant info to your questions, and not in the comments. Read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What size is your original file?

Comment: Thanks @Aerials. have made modifications as suggested.Hope this is Ok?

Comment: What does the response say? Try console.log(JSON.parse(response)) or Logger.log(JSON.parse(response))

Comment: It is direct image link - https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/09/20/19/42/foxtail-2769772_960_720.jpg                                                                               
    Tried anyway - SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0
    at downloadImage(Code:52:19)
    at getOrDownloadImage(Code:84:10)
    at createImageItem(Code:91:13)
    at createFormItem(Code:40:7)
    at makeForm(Code:18:5)

Comment: It looks like your url is malformed, in the "direct image link" at the end it says syntax error. Also provide Logger.log(response) or console.log(response) please

Comment: Imageurl=https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/09/20/19/42/foxtail-2769772_960_720.jpg

Comment: _PARSING FAILED   Jul 22, 2020, 7:07:36 PM Info File needs to be downloaded onto the disk_
Jul 22, 2020, 7:07:36 PM Error SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0
    at downloadImage(Code:52:19)
    at getOrDownloadImage(Code:84:10)
    at createImageItem(Code:91:13)
    at createFormItem(Code:40:7)
    at makeForm(Code:18:5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the method [createFile(name, content, mimeType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createfilename,-content,-mimetype) and passing Blob as content, hence the 4 bytes size. The content should be of type string for this method.

You want to use the [createFile(blob)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createfileblob) method, and to the returned file, [assign a name](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setnamename).

### Example:

```js
function downloadImage(folder, fileName, fileURL) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fileURL);
  if(response.getResponseCode() == 200){
    var fileBlob = response.getAs("image/jpeg");
    var file = folder.createFile(fileBlob);
    file.setName(fileName);
    return file;
  }else{
    console.log(response.getAllHeaders())
  }
}
```